# Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $f:X\to X$ a function, is $d(x,f(x))$ a lower semicontinous function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, metric-spaces

So I was trying to prove that if $f$ satisfies a special property the the function $d(x,f(x))$ is lower semicontinous but then I couldnt come up with a counter example of the following statement:
Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $f:X\to X$ a function, is $d(x,f(x))$ a lower semicontinous function
What do you guys think?

Comment: You have to assume something about $f$ to prove something about $d(x,f(x))$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the mapping is *not* lower semicontinuous.

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ (equipped with the Euclidean distance) and set

$$f(x) := \begin{cases} 2, & x=0,\\ x+1, & x \neq 0. \end{cases}$$

Then

$$d(x,f(x)) = \begin{cases} 2, & x=0, \\ 1, & x \neq 0 \end{cases}$$

is not lower semicontinuous at $x=0$.